# AVPlayer shows black screen when playing multiple Videos in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, video, swift3, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am working on `Video` player based `Application`, where I have to play multiple
`Videos` using `AVPlayer`. Each `video` has to play with some `CIFilter` effect so I am using `VideoComposition` for that.

My problem is when there is more than one `Video` in my `VideoArray` then first `Video` is playing perfectly with audio, but when it’s coming to the next Video then `AVPlayer` shows black screen but `audio` sound of the `Video` is coming. I am invoking the below common method whenever `Video` is playing:

```
private func createPlayerForVideoIndex(index: Int){

        guard let videoComposition = videoFilterComposition else { return }

        self.player?.pause()
        self.audioPlayer?.pause()

        playerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

        let video = videoClipsArray.object(at: index) as! VideoFileModel
        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url:NSURL(fileURLWithPath: video.localFilePath) as URL)
        playerItem?.videoComposition = videoComposition

        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

        playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        playerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:67, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height:250)

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)



            if !myScrollView.isDescendant(of: self.view) {

                myScrollView.frame = (playerLayer?.frame)!
                myScrollView.delegate = self
                myScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
                myScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
                myScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
                myScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

                self.view.addSubview(myScrollView)
            }

            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.pageControl)


            self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.myScrollView.frame.size.width * 4,height: self.myScrollView.frame.size.height)

            let startSeconds : Int64 = Int64(video.leftRangeValue)
            let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(startSeconds, 1)
            self.player?.seek(to: targetTime)

            let endSeconds : Int64 = Int64(video.rightRangeValue)
            self.player?.currentItem?.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(endSeconds, 1)

            self.player?.volume = videoVolumeSlider.value

            self.player?.play()
            self.audioPlayer?.play()

            self.player?.rate = video.slowFastMotionRate

    }
```

I assume, there should have the problem with above method which is calling every time for each `Video` (I mean with next video).

Can anyone please suggest me.

Comment: To be honest I didn't read full question but try separate player like create new player object  for `createPlayerForVideoIndex`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiyaNo problem, thanks for your response. When I am commenting this line "playerItem.videoComposition = videoFilterComposition", it's working fine. By the way Can you tell me how can I separate player here?

Comment: What I was thinking is you are using same player object that might be problem So I have suggested to create new player object each time.

Comment: Thats fine but I don't think the problem is with player, bcos I am getting Video sound properly, only the display goes black.

Comment: There is a hard limit of 16 video players at a time on newer devices 4 on older devices (I wanna say iphone 4s and back)

Comment: I didn't get you, what you mean here @SeanLintern88?

Comment: When I have print total layer count, I got 16 only. Can you tell me my mistake here? Thanks

Comment: In iOS, you can only play 16 videos maximum at once, You didnt say how many you was trying to play.

Comment: I have solved this issue, the issue is due to AVAsset which is not updating in VideoComposition.

Comment: @AnandGautam - What did you change to make your AVAsset update the video Composition?

Comment: @NathanaelThe issue was with the instance, I was making a new instance every time whenever I was playing a new Video. In short I was adding multiple layers.